# Correct pronoun for Hebrews 1:5-13 He or it

Tags: translation-philosophy, hebrews

In Hebrews 1:5-13 we see most translations using a masculine pronoun “He” to indicate God the Father is speaking these things

- “For to which of the angels did **He** ever say” 1:5
- “And when **He** again brings the firstborn into the world, **He** says“ 1:6
- “And of the angels **He** says” 1:7
- “But of the Son **He** says” 1:8
- “But to which of the angels has **He** ever said” 1:13

However when I read the Greek text, I don’t see any pronoun specified. The verbs, if I understand correctly, do not imply any gender. So it could be read “ For to which of the angels did He/She/It ever say”.

Why do we assume the unspecified subject of these verses is the Father? Is there some sort of contextual clue? In my mind, it seems the subject is implied to be the Scriptures, i.e. “it”.

In which case it would read,“For to which of the angels did it (the scriptures) ever say…”
This makes much more sense when considering that 1:8 is quoting the musings of David rather than the words of the Father directly written down. “But of the Son it (scripture) says”.

The only difficulty I see with this interpretation is in 1:6, because scripture did not bring Jesus into the world. I’m not an expert in verb conjugations, so could someone clarify on this? Is this the reason it must be read “He” as in the Father? Or is it possible εἰσαγάγῃ is also compatible with this interpretation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP is correct that all the pronouns in Heb 1:5-13 are implied in the Greek verbs; further, because those verbs do not have gender, the gender of the implied noun must be determined by the gender of the verb's subject.  So let us take these one at a time.

The implied subject in all these case is actually stated in V1 & 2a:

> On many past occasions and in many different ways, **God spoke** to
> our fathers through the prophets. But in these last days He [God]
> **has spoken** to us ...

This is confirmed in V5 which reports the declaration (first recorded in the Psalms)  of God about the Son.  Thus, God the Father is speaking.

The same holds true in V6 - God the Father is speaking and declaring Christ's superiority to all other creatures.  The same holds true for the rest of the chapter - God is speaking.

This can be further confirmed by looking at the first time these declarations are recorded in the Bible.  For example, V13 records the declaration of God the Father about Jesus recorded in Ps 110:1.  The same analysis always reveals the same person speaking - God the Father.